# mySQL to count by date and hour giving results as a date headed table

Tags: mysql, sql

Query I have now:

```
SELECT DATE(requestdate), HOUR(requestdate), count(*)
FROM timeseries
GROUP BY DATE(requestdate), HOUR(requestdate)
ORDER BY requestdate
```

Returns eg:

```
2018-10-12   0    7655
2018-10-12   1    876
2018-10-12   2    1344
...
2018-10-12   23   1009
...
2018-10-13   0    765
2018-10-13   1    9879
2018-10-13   2    2132
...
2018-10-13   23   876
... more days
```

Desired result eg:

```
     2018-10-12     2018-10-13     ...
0    7655           765
1    876            9879
2    1344           2132
...
23   1009           876
```

How would I do this?  (don't need a particularly performant solution)

Comment: The SQL language has a strict requirement that the number of types of columns can be determined _at query compile time_. If you want the columns to be determined by the data at execution time, as in this question, **you will not be able to do it in a single SQL statement.** There's just no way. The only thing you can do is write one query to get a list of the dates you need, and use those results to build another query dynamically. Or you can use your query in the question, and let the client language pivot the data. That's usually better practice anyway.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL pivot table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7674786/mysql-pivot-table)

Comment: Always consider handling data display related things in your application code layer (eg: PHP, C++, Java) etc